# How to see if there is any session in aws-amplify without throwing an error (npm version)

Tags: javascript, aws-amplify

I am retrieving the session with `const session = await Auth.currentSession()` but whenever there is no session, I get an error: `[ERROR] xx:xx.xxx AuthClass - No current user`

I would like to have some

```
if (/* Session exists */) {
  /* Logged in */
} else {
  /* Logged out */
}
```

without throwing an error. Is such a thing possible? I wasn't able to find anything in the docs, but it's possible I missed something because they're extensive.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can change the behaviour of the Auth.currentSession() function, but you can put the await Auth.currentSession in your own function, within a try catch block like this, and then return null or similar if there is an error:

```
async function checkLoginnStatus() {
    const session = await this.getUserSession();
    if (session) {
      // logged in
    } else {
      // logged out
    }
 }

 async function getUserSession() {
    try {
      return await Auth.currentSession(); // returns the session if there are any
    } catch (error) {
      return; // returns null
    }
  }
```